# Problem requiring lists

Tags: python, nested-lists, dictionary

The current issue im facing is comes from the following scenario. I have a script that runs a commandline program to find all files of a certain extension within an specific folder, lets call these files File A. Another section of the script runs a grep command through each file for filenames within File A. What would be the best method to store what filenames are in File A and only File A, and how could I achieve it? Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Adding an example or two would help too.

Comment: Are you trying to save the filename list in a file for use later in another program?

Comment: @ Manoj:

File "001356.doc" contains the following text within it: "001354, 001359, 001245". That text happens to be filenames. ex: 001354.doc, 001359.doc, 001245.doc

The end product I need is something like this
(001356.doc)
  -001354.doc
  -001359.doc
  -001245.doc

@ Noctis: yes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help with NetworkX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547236/need-help-with-networkx)

Comment: @user428370: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please **update** your question so it is complete and easy for people to read and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I see you were the one who asked the previous question! Why open a new one?

---

There was a recent question on this exact problem -- the structure you are modelling is a *directed graph*. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547236/need-help-with-networkx/3547323#3547323) to that question, using Python's [`networkx`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) package. Using this package is a good idea if you are going to do some post-processing of the data. However, for simple situations, you could make your own data structure. Here is a sample using an adjacency list representation of a graph; it is not difficult to use an adjacency matrix instead.

```
from collections import defaultdict
adj_list = defaultdict( set )

for filename in os.listdir( <dir> ):
    with open( filename ) as theFile:
        for line in theFile:
            # parse line into filename, say 'target'
            adj_list[ filename ].add( target )
```

This will give you a dictionary of filename -> files linked by that file.

Comment: you seem to be quite the speedy/frequent replier katrielalex, thanks for that. Is there a particular reason for using a list? Now that I think about it could one code a class structure in a similar manner?

Comment: well the answer is different for one, and your reply to this question happened to have solved a few problems.

Comment: @user428370: The overall structure here is a directed graph. To store that graph you need a data structure for it. (Just as e.g. a vector is a mathematical concept but it is stored in e.g. a list or a tuple.) There are several data structures commonly used for graphs; the two most common are adjacency lists and adjacency matrices (see Wikipedia for more info). In the above case I have implemented an adjacency list structure using a Python dictionary of sets.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "could one code a class structure in a similar manner" -- are you asking whether it would be possible to define a class to represent a graph? The answer is yes: `networkx.DiGraph` is one such class. If you're asking whether you can represent the inheritance structure of Python classes using a graph, the answer is also yes: it's called a dependency graph. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph

Comment: ok that explains everything, thank you for taking the time to assist me.